# SQLite Database Upgrade Condition

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have an android Quote application in which I have used SQLite Database for storing quotes. I have launched the first version of the application with this DatabaseHelper.

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static String DB_PATH;
        private static String DB_NAME = "SuccessQuotes";
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private final Context myContext;

        public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
            DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
            Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
        }

        // ==============================================================================


        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {

                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        // ==============================================================================

        private boolean checkDataBase() {

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                // database does't exist yet.

            }

            if (checkDB != null) {

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        // ==============================================================================

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        // ==============================================================================

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        // ==============================================================================

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

        }

        // ==============================================================================

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        // ==============================================================================

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

and my Database Activity is :

```
public class DAO {

    // All Static variables

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHandler dbHandler;

    private static final String TABLE_QUOTES = "quotes";
    private static final String TABLE_AUTHORS = "authors";
    private static final String TABLE_SETTINGS = "settings";

    // Pages Table Columns names

    private static final String QU_ID = "_quid";
    private static final String QU_TEXT = "qu_text";
    private static final String QU_AUTHOR = "qu_author";
    private static final String QU_FAVORITE = "qu_favorite";
    private static final String QU_WEB_ID = "qu_web_id";

    private static final String AU_ID = "_auid";
    private static final String AU_NAME = "au_name";
    private static final String AU_PICTURE = "au_picture";
    private static final String AU_PICTURE_SDCARD = "au_picture_sdcard";
    private static final String AU_WEB_ID = "au_web_id";

    // ==============================================================================

    public DAO(Context context) {
        dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(context);
        try {

            dbHandler.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
        try {

            dbHandler.openDataBase();

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {

            throw sqle;

        }
//      Log.e("path2", context.getDatabasePath("SuccessQuotes").toString());
        // open();
    }


    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting All Quotes
    public Cursor getQuotes(String start) {
        // Select All Query

        String limit = "15";

        if (start.equals("5000")) {
            String query_count = "SELECT COUNT(" + QU_ID + ") AS count FROM "
                    + TABLE_QUOTES;
            Cursor c_count = database.rawQuery(query_count, null);
            c_count.moveToFirst();
            Integer count = c_count.getInt(c_count.getColumnIndex("count"));
            limit = String.valueOf(count);
        }
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " ORDER BY " + QU_WEB_ID + " DESC "+ " LIMIT " + start + ", " + limit;
        //Log.i("query",query);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting All Quotes
    public Cursor getFavoriteQuotes(String start) {
        // Select All Query
        String limit = "15";

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " WHERE " + QU_FAVORITE + " = " + "1"+" ORDER BY " + QU_WEB_ID + " DESC  "+ " LIMIT " + start + ", " + limit;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;

    }

    //======================================================================

    // Getting Fav Quote from ID
        public String getFavQuotes(String strkey_id) {
            // Select All Query
            String fav = "";
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                    + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                    + " WHERE " + QU_FAVORITE + " = " + "1 AND " + QU_ID + " = " +strkey_id;
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

            if(cursor.getCount() != 0)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                fav = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QU_FAVORITE));

            }
            return fav;

        }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting All Author Quotes
    public Cursor getAuthorQuotes(String authorID,String start) { 
        // Select All Query
        String limit="15";
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " WHERE " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + authorID + " ORDER BY "+ QU_WEB_ID +" DESC  "+ " LIMIT " + start + ", " + limit;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting Selected Quote
    public Cursor getOneQuote(String quoteID) {
        // Select All Query

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES + " JOIN "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " ON " + QU_AUTHOR + " = " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " WHERE " + QU_ID + " = '" + quoteID + "'";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void addOrRemoveFavorites(String id, String value) {



        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QU_FAVORITE, value);

        // Update Row
//      database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });
        database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting All Authors
    public Cursor getAllAuthors() {
        // Select All Query

        String query = "SELECT *, COUNT(" + QU_AUTHOR + ") AS count FROM "
                + TABLE_AUTHORS + " LEFT JOIN " + TABLE_QUOTES + " ON " + AU_WEB_ID
                + " = " + QU_AUTHOR + " GROUP BY  " + AU_NAME ;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting Quotes Count
    public Integer getQuotesCount() {

        String query = "SELECT COUNT(" + QU_TEXT + ") AS count FROM "
                + TABLE_QUOTES;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Integer count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"));

        return count;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    // Getting Quote ID
    public Integer getQotdId() {

        String query = "SELECT " + QU_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES
                + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Integer id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(QU_ID));

        return id;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void updateSetting(String field, String value) {
        open();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(field, value);

        // Update Row
        database.update(TABLE_SETTINGS, values, null, null);
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public Cursor getSettings() {
        open();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SETTINGS;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public int getLastAuthor() {

        String query = "SELECT " + AU_WEB_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_AUTHORS
                + " ORDER BY " + AU_WEB_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AU_WEB_ID));

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public int getLastQuote() {
        String query = "SELECT " + QU_WEB_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_QUOTES
                + " ORDER BY " + QU_WEB_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(QU_WEB_ID));

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void addAuthor(String au_name, String au_picture, int au_web_id) {
        open();     

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(AU_NAME, au_name);
        v.put(AU_PICTURE, au_picture);
        v.put(AU_PICTURE_SDCARD, 1);        
        v.put(AU_WEB_ID, au_web_id);

        database.insert(TABLE_AUTHORS, null, v);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void addQuote(String qu_text, int qu_author, int qu_web_id) {
        open();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(QU_TEXT, qu_text);        
        v.put(QU_AUTHOR, qu_author);
        v.put(QU_FAVORITE, "0");        
        v.put(QU_WEB_ID, qu_web_id);

        database.insert(TABLE_QUOTES, null, v);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void open() throws SQLException {
//      database = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        database = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void closeDatabase() {
        dbHandler.close();
    }
```

Now if I want to update application with more quotes, which changes should I make so that the new and old users don't face any issue ?

**I know That Database Version Should Increased, I will it, but What should I put in onUpgrade method ?**

I am not expert Android developer, so Please explain me little more if possible, I will very thankful for it.
Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well the Java doc pretty much explains what needs to be done.

From Java doc

*Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it
needs to upgrade to the new schema version.*

What we do is , alter the tables whenever we have changed the table schema. 
In addition you can also perform some data migration if required. Basically its a hook which you got and you can perform any kind of compatibility logic.

cheers,

Saurav